# Is inheritance from a base class with no virtual methods bad practice?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I read an answer some time back to a question regarding dynamic_cast. The dynamic_cast failed to work because the base class had no virtual methods. One of the answers said that deriving from classes with no virtual methods generally means a bad design. Is this correct? Even without taking advantage of polymorphism, I still can't see the wrongness in doing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends what we're talking about:

- for Traits classes (no data) it's fine (`std::unary_function` comes to mind)
- for `private` inheritance (used instead of composition to benefit from Empty Base Optimization) it's fine too

The problem comes when you starts treating such a Derived object polymorphically wrt this Base class. If you ever attain such a position, then it's definite *code smell*.

*Note:* Even when noted as fine above, you are still providing the ability to use the class polymorphically, and you thus expose yourself to subtle bugs.

Comment: Good point about polymorphic usage being possible - though, if your class is properly defined as you outlined, the user has the responsibility to not go the extra mile to circumvent this.

Comment: @Ken: The problem is about this responsability. Even if unintended, a user *may* mess up and use the class polymorphically. Granted, in both cases it is unlikely. In the former because a traits does not have non-static methods, it's about useless and in the latter `private` restrict the error possibility to methods of the class and friends. Still, it may happen. The problem (at large) is a missing feature: we would like *delegation* here, not *inheritance*.

Answer (score 2):

Deriving from a class is always a valid option, for the sake of code reuse.

Sometimes, we are not looking for polymorphic behavior. That's OK - there's a reason we have that option. If this is the case, though, then consider using private inheritance instead - if your class isn't meant to be polymorphic, then there's no reason for anyone to try to use it polymorphically.

Comment: I would *not* use inheritance *just* for code reuse. Composition us much *better* suited to the task, and using Inheritance ties you much more strongly to the base class as well as expose you to subtle (conversion/hiding) bugs.

Comment: @Matthieu: A valid argument, though still arguable. It's true that it definitely requires attention, as well as responsibility on the user's end. I'll agree that composition is *usually* better, but private inheritance is still an alternative (albeit, more tricky to use correctly).

Comment: I have found private inheritance viable in two cases: as an optimization (EBO) or to override virtual methods (not concerned here). All the others are a matter of laziness/convenience. Did I mention I was pretty uptight about the Inheritance/Composition debate ?

Comment: Private inheritance is just composition (has-a instead of is-a relation). It has the additional benefit of EBO, but also of using `using` directives to directly expose certain base methods as part of the `public` or `protected` interface of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an OK example, to factor behaviors into policies (note the protected destructor):

```
struct some_policy
{
    // Some non-virtual interface here
protected:
    ~some_policy() { ... }

private:
    // Some state here
};

struct some_class : some_policy, some_other_policy { ... };
```

Another Ok example, to avoid code bloat in templates. Note the protected destructor:

```
struct base_vector
{
    // Put everything which doesn't depend 
    // on a template parameter here

protected:
    ~base_vector() { ... }
};

template <typename T>
struct vector : base_vector
{ ... };
```

Another example, called CRTP. Note the protected destructor:

```
template <typename Base>
struct some_concept 
{
    void do_something { static_cast<Base*>(this)->do_some_other_thing(); }

protected:
    ~some_concept() { ... }
};

struct some_class : some_concept<some_class> { ... };
```

Another example, called Empty Base Optimization. Not really inheritance per se, since it is more a trick to allow the compiler to reserve no space in `some_class` for the base class (which acts as a private member).

```
template <typename T>
struct some_state_which_can_be_empty { ... };

template <typename T>
struct some_class : private some_state_which_can_be_empty<T> { ... };
```

As a rule of thumb, classes you inherit from should have either virtual or protected destructor.

Comment: I find the of `public` inheritance concerning.

Comment: @Alexandre C: Both the policies and code bloat example could use composition instead (as long as EBO is not required). The CRTP example is effectively special, as it does not allow polymorphism in the traditional sense (the base class depending on the derived class).

Comment: @Matthieu: the code bloat and the policy example usually have some non trivial public interface. If you make them members, then you have to write wrappers by hand. Cumbersome in generic code and C++03 (easier with C++0x and perfect forwarding).

Comment: @Matthieu: this is not laziness. I do use these things when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance without virtual methods in C++ is nothing more than a code reuse.
I can't think of inheritance without polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Some classes in the C++ standard library have protected members (which are only meaningful to a derived class) but no virtual member functions. I.e., they're designed for derivation, without having virtuals. This proves that it must generally be bad design to derive from a class without virtuals.

Cheers & hth.,